# Special characters - Danish - In R / Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have problem with special Danish characters.
We have 3 charterers: æøå
I have a shiny application with 2 files server.R and ui.R
If I use one of the Danish characters in a comment/text inside the files, I get this error message:

*ERROR: Error sourcing C:\Users\TUEHEL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpED9tet\file2ca0775a702e*

```
        sidebarPanel(helpText("Du har mulighed for at v**æ**lge kun at se et bestemt land"), 
                     selectInput("valgtland", h3("V**æ**lg land"), 
                                 choices = salg$Country, 
                                 selected = 1)),
```

If I remove the Danish charterers it works just fine?
What to do :-) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Unicode values of the letters in escape strings:

```
c("\u00e6", "\u00f8", "\u00e5")
#> [1] "æ" "ø" "å"

"Du har mulighed for at v\u00e6lge kun at se et bestemt land"
#> [1] "Du har mulighed for at vælge kun at se et bestemt land"
```